Configurable Joint Baking Failed: Baking Motor as Rotation Motor requires that both Angular Drive
I've been trying to develop a physics-based ragdoll within ECS, utilizing Rukhanka - ECS Animation System's skinned mesh render. (ECS at this time does not support animated SMR)
At an attempt at an active animated ragdoll, I've come to realize that the 'drive' system on configurable-joints must be locked to function. Otherwise, my ragdoll's joints disconnect.
AssertionException: Configurable Joint Baking Failed for Bicep.L: Baking Motor as Rotation Motor requires that both Angular Y Drive = Locked, Angular Z Drive = Locked
Assertion failure. Value was False
Expected: True

Why is this? Does anyone know a workaround? Thank you.


